# Should we downvote off-topic questions as well as vote to close?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, scope

I've noticed a number of questions that are off-topic for Stack Overflow receiving downvotes as well as close votes.

Other than being off-topic, these are questions that show research effort, are clear, and are useful. I can see an argument for downvoting: the questions may be useful, but not within the scope of Stack Overflow. However, my view (at the moment) is that this is what voting to close is for (particularly if the question is a good fit for another SE site), and downvoting sends the wrong message.

I vote to close but don't downvote. How do others think such questions should be treated?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238360/165773 "you need to realize that votes (down or up doesn't really matter) are primarily intended to help site visitors, not askers or answerers..."

Comment: Downvotes indicate you do not find the question useful. If it's not in the scope of SO it usually isn't helpful in SO and should be downvoted - especially new questions.

Comment: @gnat - Thanks for that link. The points made there are pretty convincing. I think I'll be changing my habits. :)

Comment: How does down voting these questions "send the wrong message"? It sends the message that they are not welcome on Stack Overflow, which seems to me like it is the right message. Certainly you don't *have* to downvote if you don't want to (although I'd say that voting to close is nearly obligatory). Beyond that, in my experience, the truly well-written, well-researched question that is also off-topic is quite rare. Usually people smart and conscientious enough to ask a good question also know what topics they should not ask.

Comment: @CodyGray - Well, my thinking at the time (which has changed after reading gnat's comment and link) was that a downvote indicated that the question either showed inadequate research effort, was unclear, or was not useful, and the real problem was none of those, but simply that SO was simply the wrong place to ask. Put another way, a downvote is appropriate for questions that have problems that need attention; a close vote is for good questions that simply shouldn't be on SO (as well as for sufficiently bad questions). But as I say, my thinking has changed.

Comment: It may not be _worth_ downvoting reasonably well-written off-topic posts -- one only gets a certain number of votes per day and there's plenty of good and bad that may be more deserving of yours. But I generally agree that "not useful" encompasses "not a good fit for this site". (As does "shows research effort": what research could be more basic than where to ask?)

Comment: @JoshCaswell [there you go](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269707/839601) - tweaked to account for the differences and posted as an answer

Comment: A question that is off-topic, unless it's very borderline, does **not** show enough research effort - the first thing an asker should research is if the question is welcome on the site where he intends on asking it.

Comment: @l4mpi - many of the close reasons are arbitrary and capricious in their application, and have changed frequently over the site history, so it's fairly specious to claim that asking something deemed off topic by a user or two at the present instant in time necessarily indicates a lack of research, especially if the body of the post shows substantial research.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: There's a wide gulf between "usually" and "always", though.  There are good and useful questions that are off-topic on SO because of the way SO works rather than because of their subject matter.

Comment: @l4mpi: You're asking for people to have a complete understanding a community's norms and mores before their first interaction with it?  Really?  People asking questions on SO are usually trying to figure out how they can solve a technical problem.  I expect them to have done their research on their technical problem.  I'm willing to help out a little bit when they fall afoul of SO's customs.

Comment: @tmyklebu I do not expect new users to have a _complete_ understanding of SO/SE (we even have 10k users who don't know that SEs goal is _not_ to help individual users!), but I do at least expect a _basic_ understanding. While I would optimally like people to _lurk more_ before even beginning to participate (be it asking or answering), the least one can expect is that they spend 15-30 minutes reading about the format of SE, checking if the topic and intent of the question vaguely matches the site description, and search for their problem. According to many people, I still expect way too much.

Comment: @l4mpi: People think: "This is a place to ask programming questions.  I thought a bunch and googled a bunch and couldn't find an answer.  I should ask my programming question here."  Then we tell the ones who aren't asking good programming questions to go away.  The ones who are asking good questions will *still* need some help because they'll ask for recommendations or something.  We want their questions.  Let's not tell them to go away or yell at them for "not having done enough research" or whatever.  Let's guide them into asking good questions instead.

Comment: @l4mpi: Put another way, I agree that people should know what a programming question is and what a programming question isn't before posting on SO.  I don't agree that they should know why recommendation questions are banned, or why code reviews go elsewhere, or exactly where the line between a programming question and a sysadmin question is.  I think we need to help new users with that stuff.  Whether we do so nicely or brusquely should really depend on whether we estimate the new user is likely to contribute positively or negatively to the site.

Comment: @tmyklebu We're currently not even telling the users who don't do any thinking at all to go away (at least not until it's way too late, when they've been questionbanned after asking their nth crap question). Anyways, someone who asks a recommendation question on SO _did not do enough research about SO_ because the "how to ask" page clearly states that's off-topic; they should be downvoted as _that type of question isn't welcome here_. And re "helping", please don't fall into the trap of thinking you can't downvote _and_ help - help can be linking to howtoask and/or explaining SO in this case.

Comment: @tmyklebu and the argument of "don't downvote or criticize people who could be valid contributors" is so flawed I'm not even going to start attacking it. I've downvoted quite a lot of bad posts and written direct (some might call it harsh) comments to many people, and the response was mostly positive. People who want to contribute mostly _want to know where they did something wrong_ and want to be told so in a direct manner.

Comment: @l4mpi: Where did I ever say you shouldn't criticise people?

Comment: @tmyklebu you told me I shouldn't `yell at them for "not having done enough research"`. While I won't exactly yell, I won't sugarcoat my criticism either.

Comment: @l4mpi: Neither should you.  But doing the technical research and getting a feel for SO's customs are two different things.  Like I said, I'd expect the former but not the latter.

Comment: Incredible... usually behave like BOFH.. how could you Ipnotize them to act in a civil way? How could you got not downvoted? :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Abstaining of voting down off-topic questions essentially deprives site visitors of important information.

To understand why, you need to realize that votes (down or up doesn't really matter) are primarily intended to help site visitors, not askers or answerers.

If a visitor finds tag page filled with non-negative score off-topic questions that are just "waiting to be closed", this will make them think that such questions are appropriate.

When close-worthy questions are voted down, it helps visitors to find out what kind of questions are welcome at the site and what are not, and potentially saves them from trouble of asking their own off-topic question, only to find out that it gets closed.

---

Particularly regarding off-topic posts that [deserve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/165773) to be migrated to other sites, it is worth noting that migrated questions are [deleted at source site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/165773), so that downvotes don't even impact asker's reputation. Only effect these may potentially have is contributing to [question block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773) but even this can *only* happen if user persists in asking inappropriate questions. Fair enough?

<sub>Tweaked and re-posted from [similar discussion at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238360/165773).</sub>

Comment: "this will make them think that such questions are appropriate." Many of them are appropriate.  Upvotes serve as an important way for the community to register disagreement with the closed status.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see. Wrongly closed, or edited into shape for reopen questions do deserve upvotes - in that sense, these are no different than regular open questions. Though the asker wrote about the questions that they consider worthy of closure - my answer addresses this

Comment: @gnat - do you have any citations that talk about this in the context of user behavior/psychology? I do a fair amount of reading on the intersection of Security Engineering and Security UX for high level design work, and the UX studies I read would kind of indicate otherwise. That is, if you provide +/- or good/bad, then some users will be able to use the indicators to make a decision. But its not all users all of the time (or most users most of the time); and its best to avoid asking the user to make a decision (that means security software must *Defend, Don't Ask*).

Comment: @jww as I explained in [comment to your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281114/reinforce-positive-behavior-on-author-initiated-deleted-questions#comment133814_281114), there's more in that than simple +/- idea; Stack Exchange system uses question score below -1 in a multiple ways, in order to make things more appealing for site readers / visitors

Comment: @gnat It's meant to help visitors: but a question which may be useful to a visitor is downvoted because it might be slightly better suited to one of the hundreds of other stacks? The vast majority of visitors are people who navigate through the internet to read material on SO, not to post their own  questions. When it is possible for a good question that arguably may be better suited elsewhere (e.g. SO vs programmers or vs computer science, etc.) is barred from having good answers it really demands that one questions the mentality of someone who thought up this idea in the first place.

Comment: @Duncan questions better suited to other site should be migrated; FWIW migration clears negative score off the question if there are votes down (positive score is preserved). Migrated questions are available through web search engines without problems; if these are indeed useful, these gain visits and views just like any other question at Stack Exchange

Comment: @gnat But those downvotes aren't removed from the original stack are they (despite the question itself being removed)? I believe that certain stacks have higher preference with search engines; so the real issue is that similar questions are slightly more likely to be linked in the sidebar of a question posted within a stack which specifically targets that subset of question. Creating a backlog of vote to close + move requests (not to mention ill will) to that end is odd. Last time it happened to me I just ended up having 2 delete the question and vowing not to return to that particular stack.

Comment: @Duncan stabs of migrated questions are eventually deleted from originating site (as if there was no question there at all). These are gone from web searches and from asker's profile, along with any downvotes that could be there...

Comment: ...as for site-specific preferences for search engines, it's quite unlikely and first of all it is because this would harm efficiency of search engine itself. Engine that fails to find useful content because it applies some artificial notion of "site popularity" to rate it, would have rather severe competitive disadvantage

Comment: Downvoting off-topic questions quickly sends them to oblivion, where it's unlikely to get enough eyeballs on it to actually close it as off-topic, which prevents the poster from learning about other sites where their question may be more appropriate.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy well that's probably a serious concern for someone primarily interested in "redirecting" those who don't know. For those who prefer to focus on learning and contributing in _on-topic_ questions, it's minor

Comment: @gnat:  Having your question closed as off-topic is a far clearer signal of what's wrong with your question than a single off-topic vote and a couple downvotes.  It's not just about redirecting the off-topic questions, but helping the community members understand what's on and off topic.  Closed questions also seem to be lower in search results than simply downvoted ones, so there would also be less clutter for people looking for answers, which is the whole point of SO and SE>

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy that's for sure, closing is the right thing for these questions for the reasons you pointed. I feel though that voting down doesn't make such a big obstacle here. If the question is voted down, as you say, "to oblivion", it is most likely that some of the voters would also vote / flag it for closure, sending it to the review queue which has no notion of oblivion. It's hardly a coincidence that rep required for voting down (125) substantially exceeds requirement to flag for close (50)

Comment: Can you give me an evidence based reason proving that those question are "unappropriate"? Otherwise, please, accept the modificaion: "in my opinion"

Comment: @gnat: is it an opinion or you know for sure? Why don't you specify your thought and leave it ambiguos? We are not on Yahoo Answer, we must be precise here.

Comment: @Revious this was discussed in details in first comments under my answer. Please abstain of vandalising the text I wrote because it states exactly what I meant to state

Comment: @Revious - It is completely out of bounds for you to be adding language to gnat's answer after he specifically rejected that language. You're putting words in his mouth to which he objects. It doesn't matter whether you understand his reasons or not, or whether you consider his reasons valid or not. Speak with your own voice and stop trying to force someone else to use your words.

Answer (score -15):

There are a few questions that I've upvoted, answered, voted-to-close-as-off-topic, and left a note as to why.  That is, all four on the same question.  This happened when the asker asked a clear, interesting question, showed that he had a level of understanding where an answer would be worthwhile, but the question was fundamentally a recommendation question or something else that attracts scummy answers by its nature.  I believe that this encourages the right behaviour from all parties:

- The asker is encouraged to come back and ask a clear, interesting, and on-topic question in the future and is told how better to do that.
- Other people seeing the question don't feel bad about casting a close vote on this clear and interesting question, so it may get closed faster.
- The "visitors" see very explicitly why the question is unsuitable for SO and how it's not because it's crap.
- Importantly, it does *not* serve as a spam magnet because it gets closed.

Comment: "The asker is encouraged to come back and ask a clear, interesting, **and on-topic** question in the future" - why should they do so? Said differently, they're not at all discouraged from asking another off-topic quesiton in that manner - they got an answer and even got rep for it due to your upvote. Furhtermore, as you're answering and upvoting the question, you're sending the wrong signal to everybody else - "questions like this should be upvoted and answered".

Comment: @l4mpi: Why should they do so?  Maybe because they want an answer to their new on-topic question?  Also, they're humans, not robots; humans respond to being told "that sort of thing isn't welcome here, and this is why."  You're welcome to provide statistical evidence that this "sends the wrong signal to everybody else;" my intuition, gained from years of interacting with humans, suggests otherwise.

Comment: @l4mpi: The trouble with recommendation questions is not that they're inherently bad in some way; they're banned because they attract spam based on the most tenuous of connections to the original question.  This solution makes the asker unlikely to ask a recommendation question in the future, but at the same time he gets his answer and the spam problem is nipped in the bud.

Comment: But they _are_ inherently bad. In fact, disallowing them is _not_ due to spam in the first place, but due to _opinionated answers_. They're simply not answerable in a way that meets the SO criteria for answers in most cases. They're often either too broad if OP doesn't give very specific requirements or too narrow (== too localized) if OPs requirements are very specific. Even voting on the answers is mostly a popularity contest and not an indication of usefulness. All of this is unhelpful to future visitors (and no, we don't care about helping OP _if it doesn't also help future visitors_).

Comment: @l4mpi: There are tons of recommendation questions that won't attract uselessly opinionated answers.  There are far fewer that won't attract spam.  "What package can I use to do sparse Cholesky factorisation in a C program?" is a recommendation question that has about two possible reasonable answers, both of which will help future visitors and neither of which are likely to attract strong opinions.  It's still a bad fit for SO because anyone who wants to hawk their crappy commercial numerical code will take the opportunity to do so.

Comment: `both of which will help future visitors` - this is where you're missing an important point: all answers to these questions can only ever help people _by directing them to an external resource outside of SO_. These answers are thus only valid as long as the external resource exists and completely useless when it's gone. In fact, if the external website moves or the project is cancelled, all these questions and answers are doing is to pollute the google search results with useless content. And all of this doesn't matter anyways, because the community decided these questions are unwelcome here.

Comment: @l4mpi: That's a really asinine argument in quite a lot of cases, including this one.  I'd put money on SO going away or becoming useless long before CHOLMOD or METIS go away or become useless.

Comment: Yes, SO is currently in the process of becoming useless due to severely relaxing the quality standards (Don't believe me? Try to get a _hard_ question in a high-volume tag answered nowadays without posting a bounty...) And I've no idea about which case you are talking, but I am strictly talking about the case mentioned by OP: "the questions may be useful, but not within the scope of Stack Overflow" - thus they should always be downvoted _in the scope of Stack Overflow_.

Comment: @l4mpi: Yeah, it's pretty close to useless for askers today.  My take, based on experience trying to find interesting questions to answer, is that the concentration of good questions is simply too low.  Like, 1 in 50 or 1 in 100 or something.  Raising the concentration of good questions is therefore 50 or 100 times easier to do by getting more good questions into the pool than by getting rid of the bad ones.  (I see no reason to be merciful to bad questions.)

Comment: @l4mpi: [This guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3661919/matmul), for instance, got scared off after it became clear that asking his (good, relevant, interesting) questions on SO was going to be more trouble than it's worth.  I'd rather not have too many repeats of that situation in the future.

Comment: Umm, that guy asked if he could write a multipart tutorial on SO, which he also wanted to mix with questions of his own. I'm not saying this content is bad in general, but it's totally unfit for SO for a whole bunch of reasons - he should just post it at his personal blog or whereever, but _not on SO_. If he "got scared off" from SO in general because he was told that this content is unfit for SO, too bad, but that's _his_ problem, not ours. And I'm all for repeating this - if someone else asks if he can post content here that does not fit the SO model, of course we should tell them so again.

Comment: @l4mpi: Have a look at his other questions, including the deleted one.  The deleted question was way too broad (so it was correctly closed/deleted), but the way you get that across to a human (at least to a human who can contribute positively) is by guiding him toward a behaviour that's more agreeable.  That's not really what he got.  And no, it's not "his problem, not ours"---a lower signal-to-noise ratio affects the SO community at large.  It's more "our problem, not his"---he can freely take his signal elsewhere.

Comment: "scummy answers". The arch nemesis of toxicnerdism

Answer (score -15):

IMHO, it depends.

Sloppy questions should be downvoted and closed. Accurate off-topic questions should be just closed.

Concept of justice:

> The amount of punishment must be proportionate to the amount of
>   unfair advantage gained by the wrongdoer.

And this is ruined by current "Meta consensus" - **downvote them all, we need to make them all easy to delete**.

Case: A new author spends some time to write an accurate off-topic question, e.g. "open question". It was upvoted to +8 till the moment it was dug out by reviewers and then got -11 downvotes (to compensate upvotes and push to minus). When a sloppy question "make my homework" (with zero amount of work, and zero people enjoyed it) will get -3 votes. This is a clear injustice and is counterintuitive for new authors.

Comment: Downvoting is not primarily a form of punishment; thinking that it is primarily punishment is a fundamental misunderstanding of the voting system. (There's a small punishment for a downvote, but that's secondary. And even that goes away if a question is deleted or migrated to another SE site.) The primary purpose of downvotes is for the overall benefit of the community, to signal that a question isn't going to be worth time and attention from others, and to serve as an example of something that isn't right for SO.

Comment: Punishment is penalty, and downvote is straightforward penalty on rating. All other thoughts are too complex for new authors. -8 is bigger shock than -3. If you want to care more about new authors you need accept it.

Comment: @Roman I think your view of a new author is not universal and seems to be based entirely on your own pre-conceived notions of what a new author may or may not be thinking. Maybe you need to consider that your view might be incorrect, and it might even be a possibility that others have done research on the topic, where it doesnt seem you have.

Comment: I would like to see your other arguments.

Answer (score -17):

I feel disgruntled when my question is rated under 0.

You can read a great book about it(http://www.abookapart.com/products/designing-for-emotion).

Maybe another rating should be great and less hateful… or just a minus -.

Many questions (and mine) are not great for a member with high reputation (30K), but useful for the others (included a user from Google Search). I don't make conference I go to.

**Stack Overflow is great** and **the best way** to have a good answer (without deprecated code or noise).

My English is not perfect, and my coding neither. When I ask question, it's after a long Google search and Stack Overflow search…

**First point**: my question are not perfect; but some anonymous people says it's not clear/useful (and downvote) and some nice people write good and helpful answer (they are wizards or teachers)!

**Last point**: there is no stupid question; all questions are useful, especially in web languages. The people who invented HTML and CSS did this for everybody.

Comment: There most certainly *are* bad questions.  There are *lots* of questions that are *not* useful.  We see hundreds of them every single day on this site.  Providing high quality and useful answers also requires certain minimum standards in the question.  The reason you see so many great answers on this site is precisely because so much effort is spent to get rid of (or fix) low quality questions.

Comment: Yes, I'm ok with that but my question with at this time a  hateful -4 is a good example…
We cant discuss ?

Comment: We are discussing it.  The fact that people disagree with your position is in no way being hateful, nor is it preventing you from discussing it.  Other users have the ability to express their own opinions through votes just as you have the ability to express yours in your post.