# Answering a question which you vote to close as off-topic

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, scope

There are often times when a question is not relevant on Stack Overflow, especially when it's simply asking for technical help, rather than programming, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618884/using-time-machine-on-mac).

If such a question is simple to answer quickly, I may both answer the question and mark it to close with the reason being "off topic". As you can see in the example question, some will answer the question, but still notify the OP that the question shouldn't be on SO.

Is answering the question a bad thing to do here, as it may be encouraging people to continue to post  off-topic questions on SO, or is it simply deemed helpful and correct to both answer and close the question?

As the OP is probably being encouraged by having their question answered, I suspect it is the wrong thing to do, in which case, should such an **answer** be voted down?

Comment: Answering and then voting to close is a bit like [kicking away the ladder](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=kicking+away+the+ladder). By voting to close you're by definition trying to prevent others from answering.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, I suppose it could be thought of that way, if that is the intention and reason behind voting to close, rather than due to the question not being suitable for SO.

Comment: I wish more people voted them down than it is done today. Some people think that only the questions are the culprit. +1 to this question, naturally.

Comment: No no, nothing to do with intention/reason: that's [the *definition* of closing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Voting to close = voting to prevent (other) answers from being posted.

Comment: `By voting to close you're by definition trying to prevent others from answering` - yes exactly. Close it, prevent further answers.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett _By voting to close you're by definition trying to prevent others from answering._ You're right to say this would be the correct by definition, because in reality this is not what happens. I've seen many, many questions voted to be closed and still having people around answering them. The worst case are the duplicated ones.

Comment: Anyway... I've answered a few myself when I joined the site. Now I just vote do close it and also downvote it.

Comment: It seems to me as though the more reputed members do the close voting and the new members, desperate to increase their reputation, blindly answer anything that they can, whether off topic or not... of course, we also have the situation that many newer members don't even know what is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've answered general computer questions before and then voted to migrate them to SU.  (I wouldn't be surprised if half my rep there is from such questions.)  I don't see a problem with that.  If it's a decent question that'd find a good home on another SE site, but i rarely visit there and i know the answer here, why shouldn't i answer?

Comment: If you answer a question then vote to close it and it is closed, you should lose any rep gained from it.

Comment: @user3791372, What if you answer, the OP reveals their hidden information in a comment on your answer (showing the question is totally more ridiculously off-topic than you thought), you delete your answer, and then vote to close?

Comment: @developerwjk depends which way the wind is blowing

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If a question is off topic then please **don't answer**.

By answering off topic questions you are encouraging people to ask more of them. The fact that the question gets closed later doesn't matter to the OP - they have their answer.

If off topic questions are closed without answers then that sends the strongest signal that asking them is a waste of time.

As to whether the answer should be down-voted or not, ultimately that's a personal thing, but on balance it's probably a good thing to do as it will hopefully discourage people from answering similar off topic questions in future.

Comment: related: [Should we downvote off-topic questions as well as vote to close?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269700/839601)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks Chris, I expected this to be the case and have edited to the question to query if such an answer should be down-voted.

Comment: I noticed that you deleted the answer to that question, with a suitable comment.  Why not auto-delete answers to [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630209/why-use-simd-if-we-have-gpgpu) that are successfully close-voted by the community?  This would send a pretty clear message.  And if the question is eventually successfully re-opened, the answers could be auto-undeleted.  Would make your life easier?

Comment: @RobertCrovella - I think that's been brought up before on Meta Stack Exchange. I can't remember the details but I'm pretty sure that the consensus was to not do that. There might be questions that were on topic at one point that are now closed and it would be a shame to lose that information (for example).

Comment: Also, it smells of bad sportsmanship, as you effectively reduce "competition" by depriving others from contributing answers.

Comment: I liked the answer until "but on ..."

Answer (score 5):

In short, NO, not without a stronger consensus and much clearer guidance.

Question votes do not depend on the relevance or quality of the answers, nor should answer votes depend upon the relevance or quality of the question.

Once an answer is provided if it is good and downvoted the signals are confusing, to say the least.

However, “the stick” says stamp on questioners polluting the site with off-topic questions, “the carrot” says in the long term co-operation is better where a desire to help, and appreciation for help, comes across clearly.

Either may be appropriate but if downvoting an answer because the question is deemed off topic (bearing in mind there are grey areas where opinions may differ) there is all the more reason to explain such a downvote.

I have both answered a question and downvoted it in my time and admit a degree of inconsistency. A factor I take into account is the reputation of the OP. The more rep the more the chances that I will “bend the rules” to try and help (despite the theory that those Q posters should know better - they may be outside their area of expertise and/or be showing no sign of repeat offending).

Similarly for those posting a question for the first time, specially if I can somewhere slip in mention that, for SO, there is a better way (eg a different SE site).

For those who repeatedly ask off topic questions I think downvoting of answers should be considered, but do not do so myself since, as I understand it at present, this is not the approved approach, though as I understand your question, it asks what the approved approach is. We know active meta participants are a very small proportion of the total number of users with the right to downvote so without something much clearer than we have at present I think we must rely on “This answer is not useful” for guidance. In my opinion a good answer just does not fit within such guidance.

There is also that the system is geared up to incentivise “good housekeeping” and even if only temporary (off topic questions will presumably eventually be deleted and any -1’s then reimbursed) for a while downvoting answers for the sake of discouraging off topic questions is “back to front” (penalises those doing the housekeeping) – and also eats into the daily vote allowance.

From a personal perspective, I already have downvotes rather out of proportion to upvotes (2:1) and would prefer not to increase that ratio, even though most of the downvotes were for off-topic questions.

It seems many OP’s do not care about votes (they just want a solution to their problem) yet -1's to questions may be more effective in discouraging unwanted behaviour (eg question bans) than votes against their answers. As far as I can tell, others are generally reluctant to do so however (the average for the most recently closed 50 questions is between -3 and -2).

A compromise for the time being my be simply do not to upvote the answers in such circumstances.

Question can’t be answered while closed, so any answer must have been posted before “due process” is complete. Many times I have seen questions closed that clearly should not have been, at least for the reason stated. Answerers as well as questioners may be new to the system and not yet have read up on swathes of meta to fully appreciate the nuances of what is and what is not on topic. A downvote for their well-intentioned effort could be very discouraging.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9QR.gif

Answer (score 3):

You can submit a comment to the posting instead of an answer.  The comment can briefly state the answer and point to a better forum in which to get a more detailed answer for the question.  You can then also vote to close and leave a second comment explaining why you voted to close.  This approach treats everyone with respect.

When people ask off topic questions, they often do not know where to find an appropriate forum.  Politely redirecting them is more effective at addressing poster ignorance than is anonymously downvoting and closing.

Also, if you submit your brief answer in a comment instead of in an answer, you give the original poster the ability to delete their question.  By contrast, if you post your answer as a full blown answer, then the poster is not able to remove their question, and stack overflow ends up littered with a bunch of irrelevant postings.

Comment: [If a question is offtopic it means that we shouldn't be answering it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270420/1159478).  That's the whole point of closing questions, to say that they shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Yet you could still comment on closed questions.
I like CodeMed's response. Sure, we could choose to be jerks about it and leave the poster completely confused as to why he/she is not getting responses, or we could tell them where to place their question so that they know better next time. I know which one sounds more constructive..

Comment: @daOnlyBG Telling them where the appropriate place to ask their question is is *entirely different* from answering their question.  One is helpful, one is harmful.

Comment: @Servy yeah, I could agree with that. On second thought, perhaps CodeMed should specify as to why we should give a "quick" answer as opposed to "no answer" at all. Furthermore, there are people who carelessly post very work-intensive questions without bothering to show they've put effort into answering the questions before asking. I don't think those posters even deserve comments, much less answers.

Comment: Most users of this site have very few reputation points and do not ask or answer many questions.  They find the site through the search engines.  If we are gracious hosts during their visit, by pointing them in the right direction and giving a helpful comment, they might be more inclined to start using the site more than they might be if we just anonymously downvote them and vote to close without explaining or pointing them in the right directions.

Comment: @CodeMed By all means, take the time to explain in detail if you want why the question that they posted isn't appropriate for the site or what they could do to fix it.  That is also fine.  Answering the question that the site has specifically determined shouldn't be answered isn't helpful though, it's harmful.

Comment: You are being a little extreme, Servy.  I agree not to post an answer as an answer, because that makes it impossible for the poster to delete their off-topic posting.  However, spending a few minutes to write a comment or two that gets the person on their way is just good manners.  Keep in mind these are not people who spend all their time learning the rules of the site.  They are generally newbies who find the site from google.  Giving them a helpful suggestion, a referral to the appropriate other site, and a vote to close is better. A decent person will delete their posting after that.

Comment: @CodeMed, I completely agree with your last comment here - we should be giving a positive view of the SO community, even if if we don't help with the question being asked.

Comment: @CodeMed The whole reason that we close questions in the first place is that *significant* evidence has been shown that trying to answer these types of questions *is harmful to the community*.  It doesn't matter if the answer is posted as an answer or as a comment, the result is the same.  This is not just a matter of courtesy.  After all, if the person posting the question were being courteous then they wouldn't be posting inappropriate questions.  Not answering a question is not being uncourteous.  Politely informing them of the problems with the question is being *very* polite.

Comment: @CodeMed Going out of your way to cause problems for the site in order to encourage people to continue to mis-use the site is being *actively harmful*.  You're encouraging inappropriate behavior and expending limited resources of the site, resources that could be better spent answering the questions of people that took the time to post quality appropriate questions.  And encouraging people to then delete the content the community creates, therefore ensuring nobody but them could benefit is *the exact opposite of this site's founding values*.

Comment: @Merlin069 Your statement is radically opposed to CodeMed's comment.  He's saying that *we need to be answering inappropriate questions, and that not answering them (politely and constructively) is inappropriate.

Comment: You are being extreme, Servy.  If we treat the newbie off-topic posters like human beings, they will be more inclined to learn the rules of the site.  They will feel good about deleting their off topic postings. Your extreme viewpoint would drastically limit the number of users of the site by alienating the vast majority.  I am in the top 50% of users, and I only have 600 points.  Most users are newbies with only a few points who don't know the rules and who post off topic.  You will lose the majority of users if you are so rigid.

Comment: @CodeMed I don't think Stack Overflow is about getting vast numbers of users. A vote-to-close and possibly a hint in a comment about where, and maybe also what, they should be asking (if they asked in SO, they might not be clear on what they are asking) is being kind.

Comment: @Servy, how is my statement opposed? CodeMed was stating that taking time "to write a comment or two that gets the person on their way" and that is in agreement with my statement that I agree that "we should be giving a positive view of the SO community".

Comment: @CodeMed If you interact with new users by disregarding the rules, stating that they don't matter, and rewarding them for breaking them, not only will they not learn to follow the rules, they'll either not learn that there are rules at all, or they'll learn that the rules don't matter and aren't actually enforced, and that they should be encouraged to break them whenever they want.  That's the example you're trying to set.  SO, by design, is not here to appeal to everyone.  It's here to appeal to the people who *want* to be in a community with stricter rules.  That's it target audience.

Comment: @Merlin069 CodeMed is saying that we should *answer the question in comments* and not just explain to the user how to follow the rules.  You stated that we should not.  Those two are opposed.

Comment: @Servy, Ah I see, you interpreted "write a comment or two that gets the person on their way" as giving the OP an answer, whereas I'm interpreting it as advising them as to where to go to get the answer.

Comment: @Merlin069 No, I interpreted this as saying he should given an answer: `You can submit a comment to the posting instead of an answer. The comment can briefly state the answer`.  That's not particularly ambiguous or open to interpretation.  It's saying we should answer the question.

Comment: @Servy, If you read what I wrote, it says I agreed with the last comment made by CodeMed. This comment I refer to is the comment above my comment which concerns "giving a positive view of the SO community". I did not state that I agreed with the section of CodeMed's answer which states "You can submit a comment to the posting instead of an answer"

Comment: Enough already!

Answer (score 3):

What I do is the same as you. And I believe it is the best way, since our close queues take so long to get processed in many cases.

And in many cases, questions about general software etc don't actually get closed anyway - just search the site for Excel questions for example. Excel formulae should not be on our site, but there they are. (Just look at the Related posts to my link below - almost all of these should be burned.)

As I see it, if I can offer a good, real, true answer to such a question, it might prevent noise and incorrect answers from being made. Just because a question is closed, it doesn't mean that the wrong info is removed - and I don't think it is right for us to have incorrect answers on our site.

So I answer and vote to close, in the hope that the question is shut down with correct info on it e.g.

- [Split multiple names separated by semicolon into separate cells - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562377/split-multiple-names-separated-by-semicolon-into-separate-cells-excel)

---

As it so happens, it turns out I've chosen a very bad example, and Excel formulae actually are considered programming (Thanks Alexei for the link). But I stick by my reasoning above, even though the example provided turns out to be invalid.

Comment: Side note: not sure why linked post was closed instead of simply downvoted as not showing efforts - asking about [Excel formulas](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875/are-excel-formulas-on-topic) is considered ok.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hmmm, thanks for the link. Seems it shouldn't have been closed after all. So I (as person who started the VtC campaign) will now start the Vote to Reopen campaign on that one. That said, I'll stick to the rest of the answer for now.. In addition, I have a new topic to follow to try and answer instead of closing.

Answer (score 0):

Answering and close voting seems a bit schizophrenic in the sense that one should rather do one or the other, not both together.

However if someone would come and would do it I wouldn't mind as long as it doesn't happen all the time. I can afford so much tolerance.

However I guess in this case it's more complex. Leaving a comment saying that this question doesn't belong on SO is not the same as downvoting. Or was an answer indeed given by a close voter?

Furthermore, even with a single close vote you never know if the question is really closed eventually. At least in theory. In practise on SO currently a single close vote is an almost 100% sure sign that the question will soon be closed.

Leaves finally only the question open if answers to closed question should be downvoted. I will not take part in this. If there are people who want to give an answer within the short time I will not punish them for it. I think SO has to live with this little bit of extra motivation. Only exception: if the answer is bad - and given that the question is bad there is actually a big chance that the answer is bad too. In this case the answer (cannot see it) would most probably have been bad. If however by a miracle the answer is good I may not upvote it but downvoting... meh.

Anyway, those who can close vote probably don't care about a few virtual brownie points less.