# When/Why a question with accepted answer and more answers is deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I was wondering why a thread (question with answers) is completely removed even if an answer was accepted with 7 upvotes.

I noticed that my reputation decreased 71 points and didn't know why until I figured out that my answer was deleted, well actually the complete thread (question and all answers).

The question was:

[Remove the end of a string with a varying string length using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454334/remove-the-end-of-a-string-with-a-varying-string-length-using-php)

I know that the Reversal badge is earned when a question has -5 votes and the provided answer has 20 upvotes, so I'd like to know why that thread was deleted since it had an accepted good answer.

Edit: as an update, I think that deleting a thread might be done if the question and all answers have negative score. However, if a question has negative score and its answer has positive scores it should be closed instead of being deleted. I consider in this case that deleting a complete thread is really harder than closing it.

IMHO, I understand that removing a thread is to discourage people doing those kind of question but also it discourages people willing to help. I think that a better treatment would be to penalize question with 5 low quality flags with something like -10 (plus the downvotes) but not to penalize all the people answers since they are there to help.

Comment: A key bit of information in determining why it was deleted would be if the OP is still a real account (or if the account was deleted) or if 10k+ users deleted the question. This would then help answer your why was something deleted.

Comment: The question was deleted by 3 community users (10k+) and the OP still appears to have an account. I can only see a net score of 4 for your answer though. I'm not entirely sure why it was deleted - strikes me as should have remained closed probably, but some of the comments were - shall we say, not that productive? FWIW I've voted to undelete.

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the information. I have -71 points on that thread so I think I had 7 upvotes and 3 downvotes. I think that question was closed because OP annoyed some 10k+ users. IMHO I think that shouldn't have been closed since the answer had several upvotes, I like answering question and also I do effort to provide good answers so removing this kind of question that impacts with a big amount of score sounds a little unfair. What do you think?

Comment: Not for me to say... I'm not an expert in that field (or active in that area of the SO community), I believe the question should remain closed, but don't believe it should have been deleted. BTW, your answer was +6/-2. Does look like the community was having a bad day, and weren't too pleased by you helping a vampire etc... But - not my choice, not down to me... one of those, don't worry about it, carry on things :)

Comment: @JonClements yes, I see. It's a pitty for me I don't have answer with several upvotes so having 6 upvotes, accepted answer, and 2 downvotes (total of 71) is too much for me. Anyway, I hope community keep that question as closed but not deleted. Thanks man.

Comment: +6 = 60 -2 = -4 = so that makes 56 according to my maths :)

Comment: @JonClements lol it was accepted: +6(60)+15-4=71. Well, that's what my reputation history says :P

Comment: @fede ahh haa... forgot about that one.. makes sense then :)

Comment: Good answers don't save bad questions. Going off the Reversal badge you mentioned, you can look look the [list of answers that received it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95). You'll notice that the vast majority of them had one of two things happen: 1) The question got turned around and now has a positive score; 2) The question is now deleted.

Comment: @animuson From the list you sent me all the question have score -5 or less and they aren't deleted. My point is that the question should be closed but not deleted. I don't take it as personal of course but deleting the complete thread will get rid of the good answers and also its score. I only say that deleting is really harder than closing. I think that deleting a thread should be done if all question and answers have negative score.

Comment: If we never deleted questions just because they had positively scored answers, this site would be overflowing with some truly terrible questions and our site quality would be abysmal. A bad question is a bad question. We don't keep trash sitting around just because there's some food left in the wrapper that we might be able to eat later.

Comment: @animuson I agree with you, but bad question can have good answers even SO agrees with that. That's why Reversal (gold badge) exists for. So, as I said before... if an answer has several upvotes then the thread shouldn't be deleted but closed.

Comment: The existence of the Reversal badge is not a good reason to conclude that. As *I* said before, the vast majority of those fall into those two categories. Most of those questions do end up deleted eventually. Just because you only looked at the first few occurrences doesn't mean they all remain undeleted. We have a historical lock for truly excellent content that deserves to stay around, otherwise the community can delete these questions at will. I personally see absolutely no reason to undelete this particular question.

Comment: @animuson I understand your point. I don't agree with you but I respect it.

Comment: In addition to what Animuson said about the reversal badge, there are only 186 of them. There are nearly 8,000,000 (undeleted) questions on SO, so just over two questions per hundred thousand get it. (We. Are. The 99.998%!)

Comment: @Kevin what about the 0.002% ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270418/answering-a-question-which-you-vote-to-close-as-off-topic/270456#comment89183_270456

Comment: I've casually seen a large increase in such 'I want to do x, tell me how' questions lately. School back in.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [argument for deleting these questions is that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270605/16587):

> It's poor, it shows no effort at solving, no researched demonstrated, about 19 non-constructive comments and finally it asks for "the best solution".... That's about as bad as a question can get....

Of course, the OP could also be talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Or even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Or maybe even [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63447/how-do-you-perform-an-if-then-in-an-sql-select):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The logic that's being used to delete questions is flawed; because if we were going to apply it justly, all questions that don't show research *should be deleted*.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

No research has never been a reason to close or delete a question. Ever. It's always been a reason to downvote a question, but there is no close reason that says, "The OP didn't do any research."

The question may be lazy -- I'm not one to judge that; but if we use laziness as a reason to close or delete questions, we may as well shut down Stack Overflow. We weren't founded on that principle, and we've never codified that opinion into an operating guideline.

A question should remain open if:

1. It has a clear problem statement
2. It has a problem statement that someone would Google or Bing.
3. It has a reproducible problem (where required)

A closed question should remain undeleted if:

- It meets #2 and #3
- It has useful answers that would help someone coming from Google

A closed question should be deleted if none of the above criteria are met.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It seems that SO changed a lot from its begin and latest people got intolerant to new "lazy" questions. In my case, I like helping people no matter the kind of question they did. I also like having a growing reputation, I've never received a bounty, many upvotes and my reputation is low, so getting -71 points is a pain. As as you pointed in your question there are many many many answers with poor content a for hundred upvotes. Anyway, I like this site, I won't leave it but I think that people should be a little more tolerant and empatic.

Comment: So you think that there are going to be other people with this problem that are going to be able to find the question through a search engine?  I find the former reasonably unlikely, I find the latter virtually impossible.  That is what distinguishes this question from the examples you gave.  It won't ever help anyone else.  One person listed a set of narrow requirements specific to just him, several people did his work for him, and no person will ever benefit from the question ever again.

Comment: @Fede And yet not only are those not the values of this site, they are *actively opposed* to the values of this site, and the principles on which it was founded.  SO was designed to be a place with a high signal to noise ratio, where questions would have a standard that needed to be met, with the primary burden on the question author to ask a question deemed to be of "high quality".  You're explicitly stating that you want to encourage people to post low quality questions, you want there to *not* be a standard of quality enforced, and not only that *you want to be rewarded for doing this*.

Comment: @servy Just yesterday I needed to accomplish the very same thing the OP needed to accomplish, just in Java instead of PHP. So to answer your question, Yes, I think the question is useful for others.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So that's the first point.  Next is the second.  Would you have been able to find this question through a search engine when in that position?

Comment: @Servy if you want to keep high quality questions then SO have to remove thousand of threads like this answer details and also these question and include your answer, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957701/new-datetime-vs-defaultdatetime/13957724#13957724), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406591/async-modifier-in-c-sharp/17406717#17406717), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397983/can-a-lambda-expression-be-declared-and-invoked-at-the-same-time-in-c/11398092#11398092), etc. Before SO exists people had to

Comment: investigate, research, also decompile sources and dig into thirdparty code so for me that is an effort and I'm sure that thoundsand questions here doesn't show that effort but I can't judge that because people needs are different. So @Servy, my point is... if you want to delete new bad questions go ahead but also clean the old questions and we will see what people think when their reputation decrease more than 10k points.

Comment: @Fede You're right, there *are* thousands of very low quality questions on the site that should be deleted.  The site would be better if the community did a better job of it.  As to the three questions that you linked, what makes you feel that those questions are of low quality?

Comment: @Fede I agree whole-heartedly that we should remove the low quality content that isn't actually adding value to anyone.  If people lose reputation as a result of providing content that wasn't actually helpful, then that's a *good thing*, not a bad thing.

Comment: @Servy in that case I think you should create a new question on meta asking about that and listen to community opinions.

Comment: @Fede As you can clearly see in this question, and when it comes up on other occasions (because it does come up often enough) it's a polarizing issue that has many strong opinions on both sides.  I don't need to ask a new question to know that.  There are unfortunately quite a lot of people, like you, that want to see more low quality content, and that care far more about their Imaginary Internet Points than the value of their contributions.  This is an unfortunate reality that we live in.

Comment: @Servy I'm not going to get pulled into a debate with you; but you're mischaracterizing the reason why the question should be kept around. That's unfair.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker To be clear, *you* were asserting that the questions should be kept around because you think it would help other people.  That's of course a good reason to undelete a question.  I simply disagree with the assertion that this question would do that.  Fede isn't saying that that's why the question should be undeleted, he's not saying that it's not a bad question, he's saying he should earn rep for answering the question *no matter how bad it is or whether or not it'll actually be helpful to future visitors*.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more. This is the most sensible answer I've ever read w.r.t. deletion in both Meta and [meta.se].

Comment: Closing duplicates as duplicate is no longer OK?

Comment: @tmyklebu I'm not sure what you're referring to.  My answer never addresses duplicates because it's not related to the subject.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: You state "A question should remain open if..." and list three conditions.  This seems to imply that a well-written duplicate of another question should remain open instead of being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @tmyklebu The question wasn't about duplicates; the question was about questions that do not show research. The answer is about questions that do not show research. So, you could say, as long as it doesn't meet any other criteria for closure, it not having research is not a reason for closure.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: So poorly-researched duplicate questions should be...reopened?  As long as they meet the criteria you gave?

Comment: @tmyklebu I'm not sure what the confusion is. The reason I don't address duplicates is because the question doesn't ask about duplicates. It asks about poorly researched questions.  If it's a duplicate, that's a reason to close the question *as a duplicate*. Notwithstanding any other reason to close, a poorly-researched question is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: Hi @FedericoPiazza thank you for that comment `people should be a little more tolerant and empatic`

Answer (score 14):

I don't see a good reason for this question to be undeleted.

It's poor, it shows no effort at solving, no researched demonstrated, about 19 non-constructive comments and finally it asks for "the best solution".... That's about as bad as a question can get....

It's a poor question. I see it this way

> I need to achieve X
>
> I don't know how, so please tell me the best solution.

Just because you have got 4 upvotes on an answer does not mean that the question should remain closed and not deleted.

First thing to remember is **don't answer such poor questions**. Downvote and vote to close and move on.

If you decide to answer a poor question you automatically put yourself at risk of having the answer (*along with the question*) removed at some point.

This has happened to me before, I had my answers deleted and initially [thought WTF!?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212077/removed-question-is-it-possible-to-see-the-history-of-changes). Now I understand the reason for that is to discourage others to take example of those bad question. In case you didn't notice there are a lot of viewers on Stack Overflow - not every single person asks a question. **But** when they get stuck at some stage we want them to ask good and well researched questions. We don't want them to dump a problem at us and say "what is the best solution"/"give me teh codez".

Comment: Actually the question with your answer was edited and undeleted by yourself. Why is that okay for your post, but not for the OP's post?

Comment: @Chris there was a lot going on with that question over the last 9 months. The question itself it totally different from the `i need x give me the codez`. It would probably be more appropriate for programmers.SE but also wasn't a bad fit for SO in the end.

Comment: I can't see the deleted question, so I cannot tell. But it's a bad example for discouraging low quality questions by deleting them, when it's actually isn't deleted anymore. I agree with you, just asked for clarification.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of SO to help users? That answer could have helped a lot of future users. It was a quality answer. But apparently, in the name of overall site quality (which for some reason it doesn't take into account quality answers to bad questions) that thread was deleted when it should've stayed closed.

Comment: @Claudiu it all starts with questions. You can write a book as an answer to a poor question and it still may be deleted because 5 people found the questions not worthy a space on SO.

Comment: @mehow if you want to discourage people to avoid posting that kind of question then SO should penalize a closed question with 5 low quality flag with 10 points (besides the downvotes). But removing the complete thread not only discourage question but also people willing to help.

Comment: @Fede Yes.  You are correct.  Deleting bad questions discourages people from answering bad questions.  Instead it encourages them to spend their time answering quality questions, or helping people improve their questions before answering them.  That is *by design*.  We don't *want* people spending all of their time answering very low quality questions.

Comment: @Fede I get what you're saying however most of those questions which get closed come from new users, or users who don't care about reputation - therefore I don't think any further reputation punishments would have any sort of meaning.

Comment: @Fede To expand on me how's point, people asking these questions only really care about one thing, getting an answer.  The only way to actually stop them from continuing to ask these bad questions is for them to learn that they won't get answers when they do, which means discouraging, not encouraging, people to answer inappropriate questions.

Comment: *"I don't see a good reason for this question to be undeleted."* - well, George offered some good examples. If one of Stack Overflow's goals is to help fellow programmers, then the upvotes on the questions seem to indicate the questions should stay. (It does not speak to whether the questions should be closed or not. But a closed question still satisfies the goal of helping fellow programmers because a closed question is available to visitors).

Comment: @jww votes were misused in a those quoted questions by George. It's strange how for some posts Mods say "votes don't matter" and other "votes matter". There is no logic behind that - there are historical locks and the only reason those questions are around is because "THOSE" were initially the ones that got SE network **famous**.