# How can we discourage bandwagoning of Close Votes?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Some time ago, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678701/whats-the-minimum-required-sdk-if-i-want-to-develop-in-material-design) being closed for the following custom reason:

> [The OP had not searched at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678701/whats-the-minimum-required-sdk-if-i-want-to-develop-in-material-design#comment40131614_25678701)

That isn't a valid reason to close a question. The question is a clear, answerable question, so when I came across it, I wrote an answer. However, within minutes the question was closed due to the above mentioned reason.

It has been mentioned multiple times that it isn't a valid reason to close a question.

I quote [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270645/2982225):

> **No research has never been a reason to close or delete a question. Ever.** It's always been a reason to downvote a question, but there is no close reason that says, "The OP didn't do any research."

Also related: slugster's [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253484/2982225)

I have cast a reopen vote on the question.

How can we discourage this kind of bandwagoning of close votes?

Comment: I probably wouldn't have voted to close, but i won't vote to reopen either.  :P  The question shouldn't have even had to be asked.

Comment: That might not be a valid reason to close a question, but it is rather unclear to me why you think that question was erroneously closed. Dhruti may have closed for the wrong reason, but why do you assume that the other 4 users didn't have a perfectly valid reason?

Comment: @CodyGray: It came to the Tavern as a cv-request, so I went and saw the close votes pile up on that same custom reason. I don't know what the 5th user selected, but I saw the remaining 4 votes were cast on that particular reason. Also, I answered it only because I agree with [slugster's answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253484/2982225)

Comment: @CodyGray: Eh, I cast the reopen vote.  Y'all will have to try again, maybe with a legitimate close reason this time?

Comment: Yes, please close it with a valid close reason.

Comment: 'no research' is a downvote reason, not a close vote reason.

Comment: While it's a simple question (anybody who knows to ask the question should know where to find the answer), I wouldn't vote to close it. It's clearly asked, can be clearly answered, and is within the scope of SO. I don't see any harm in leaving it open.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, searching and researching your question prior to posting it is the very first thing listed at the top of the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page in the help center:

> #### [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search), and research
>
> ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that *haven't* helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.

Now, with that said, it's possible to ask a good question without necessarily showing research. However, many questions where the asker didn't do any research end up being questions with a lot of missing details and context that help give answerers a starting point in terms of helping.

When an asker describes in greater detail what they tried, and what they're trying to do, what they've done so far to try and resolve the situation, it gives the rest of us some context. Without context, we're more likely to have to guess at what the asker is trying to do, and we may give answers that aren't very helpful.

I'm not sure if showing research would make *this particular question* better or not, but in general, if you can provide a bit more context, it's better for everyone.

As for close votes, I'm not convinced this is bandwagon close voting. Many users on this site have put in a great deal of time and energy to help make it a great resource of knowledge for long tail programming problems, so when we see something that looks like it's poorly researched, low quality, lacking in details, or something that otherwise won't be useful to future visitors, we take some form of action.

To keep a question from being closed, the #1 tool at your disposal is *editing.* If you see people in comments indicate that they're closing a question for a certain reason, even if you disagree with that reason, go ahead and edit the post to try to fix those problems. Many times, as an advocate for a question, you're able to make a better impact on a question via editing than someone who doesn't understand the problem and just simply sees it as unclear or off-topic. Make it so people don't think that, and they won't vote to close. In fact, you'll likely pick up reopen voters by bumping the newly minted question back to the top of the main page.

Comment: I agree with everything except the last paragraph. I remember editing some half-dead questions in order to save them but it didn't matter really. They never got reopened because they never attracted enough reopen votes. So either I'm really bad at editing or SO users are very reluctant with reopen votes. If there is time one could make more research in this topic and gather some statistics. For now I would say that from my experience it is not very likely to pick up reopen votes by editing questions. I would not put much hope there.

Comment: @Trilarion - Sometimes I find a combination of editing, chat, and meta are necessary in order to get certain posts open. Editing makes people think it looks better, chat is a way to spread the word to technical experts (i.e if it's a JS question drop a link in the JS chat room) and meta can be used to get SE experts to look at the question...

Answer (score -3):

> How can we discourage this kind of bandwagoning of close votes?

Is this effect really there and if so how big is it?

We would need to make some random control experiments where (for a subset of bad questions) a smaller number of negative votes is shown and then some Bayes statistics on that. You can then find out if for example the probability to get a second downvote is really that much higher than the probability to get the first one.

How can you discourage this effect?

If it exists, make it more expensive. Downvotes could cost 2 rep instead of 1. Make this and you'll see less of them. But of course this also has unwanted side-effects.

And otherwise?

Encourage resubmission of improved questions without initial penalty at least in the beginning of a career on SO. So if a question gets closed (that is not the end of the world or SO), give hints to the questioner what went wrong and give him the change to replace this question with a better version but he/she should start again without any downvotes.

If the resubmitted question is good, we reached our goal and everything is fine. If not we can still whack the questioner with a big stick, so the threshold for a question ban still stays whereever it was.

Comment: "Encourage resubmission of improved questions without initial penalty at least in the beginning of a career on SO." - This reads like it basically amounts to raising the threshold for question bans, which would be an extremely bad idea. If anything, we need to ban more people, definitely not less. If someone posts their first few questions with complete disregard for SO rules and culture, the correct response would be to ban them and tell them to lurk more, not to give them more hints they won't read and give them more chances to submit their crap to the site.

Comment: @l4mpi Apart from errors are inherent in any learning process I thought not about raising the threshold for question bans but actively promoting the idea of resubmitting an improved question starting at zero votes. If then the resubmitted question is bad again, feel free to take out the big club. I have nothing against it. I clarified the answer.

Comment: Downvotes of questions are free.  They don't even cost 1.

Comment: @l4mpi FWIW something like forgetting about first failure is planned for question blocks in the future: "The first question doesn't count, because we're programmers and enjoy testing gravity with our faces and some pavement from time to time..." ([Breaking down question blocks - let's talk about rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773))

Comment: @Trilarion giving new users a way to simply undo all downvotes to a quesiton seems like an even worse idea, for obvious reasons. Basically, for the bad users this amounts to getting more front page time, requiring yet more community interaction and moderation, and pissing of even more people. I believe the positive effect for a few potentially good users would be heavily outweighed by the negative effects simply because we get a whole lot of new users who simply don't seem to care at all about SO standards. The reopen queue should handle these questions anyways, why do we need anything else?

Comment: @l4mpi I would say that the additonal frontpage time is quite limited because the question ban will hit at some point while the positive effect of getting people to post better questions is totally worth it. I don't put much trust or hope into the reopen queue, not only because there is a lot of reopen fatique but especially because the downvoters never bother to come back and remove their downvote. This way just doesn't work. While deleting your bad question and posting a new and improved version is already doable ...

Comment: @l4mpi ...although if you do not improve the question the automatic ban will take effect at some point. What I want is promote and formalize this way as the better alternative to wait for reopen and wait for undoing the downvotes which just doesn't happen.