# Question got closed for being too broad, but I don't agree with it

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653658/how-to-calculate-the-broadcast-year-and-month-out-of-the-given-date) that I believe follows Stack Overflow's guidelines. The issue seems to be a common thing in TV advertising, and I thought that someone might have come up with a formula to do it. I was just hoping that somebody else might have done the work in any programming language so I can use the same formula.

It was downvoted and closed as "too broad". I received comments that I am asking other people to do my work, and that I have not shown an attempt to solve the problem.

Can anybody explain in detail what is the general problem with the question?

I don't think that it is too broad, as the formula I am asking for is similar in any programming language, SQL or spreadsheet editor.

In the meantime I wrote the formula I needed myself, and the bad thing is that I cannot post the answer because the question is closed.

Comment: So did you make any attempt at solving the problem yourself? You can solve that issue in any number of ways, you need to help constrain the problem space here. We can help you with specific issues with your code, not a research service for how broadcast calendars work.

Comment: "I was just hoping that somebody else might have done the work in any programming language so I can use the same formula" - then you're basically asking SO to find a resource for you (an algorithm in this case), or otherwise implement it from scratch, which is certainly too broad (and unclear, as you just link to a wiki page describing the concept). I agree with the closure; asking "is there a standard formula for this" isn't a constructive SO question. If you now wrote a solution yourself, edit the question to focus on the actual programming problem to get it reopened, then add the answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he does state he now wrote the formula himself in the last paragraph.

Comment: I actually solved the problem myself after the question got closed. But the thing I was asking for is very specific: extract the broadcast month out of a date. I posted the wikipedia link for broadcast calendars so I don't fill in SO with a 3 paragraph explanation of what is a broadcast calendar

Comment: @l4mpi: right, but the question itself hasn't been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Ok, I added the answer in the question body, can somebody reopen it, so I can answer it properly?

Comment: @MartinTaleski as discussed elsewhere, being able to answer the question doesn't give you a pass on it being off-topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how is it now off-topic? It asks for an algorithm / formula using a programming language.

Comment: *"It asks for an algorithm / formula"* - SO isn't a code-writing service, and we aren't here to find algorithms for you.

Comment: Yes but the problem in common, so the formula most probably already exists. There are tons of questions starting with "How to calculate..." which are asking for similar stuff. Take this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points

Comment: *"the formula most probably already exists"* - so **go and find it**. If you want someone to go and find it for you, per another close vote reason (emphasis mine): *"Questions asking us to recommend **or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial **or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*. Dredging up a question from 2008 doesn't prove anything; site standards have evolved over time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe not that I disagree with _SO isn't a code-writing service_, but if presented in the right way, OPs question is arguably more on topic than the thousands of low level questions that stem from an inability to do basic debugging or read a tutorial (and those are usually not closed as long as they contain enough details to be answerable). I agree however that it's not a good question given the way it is currently asked.

Comment: @l4mpi perhaps, but *"more on topic"* than basic failures to debug (if I see one more [tag:python] question where the correct answer is *"you got a `SyntaxError` because you made a syntax error"*...) is a **really** low bar!

Comment: @jonrsharpe the difference between OPs question and the thousands of python syntax errors (which I hate just as much as you - and don't even get me started on the AttributeErrors) is that it is useful for everybody else who has to deal with broadcast calendars. IMO, given this potentially useful information, we should not focus on why the current presentation is off-topic, but if and how it could be made on-topic.

Comment: @l4mpi *"we should not focus on ... how it could be made on-topic"* I agree, and I think that *has been done*, but the OP's response was *"Ok, I added the answer in the question body"*...

Comment: Ok, I added example values, and I think the question is good now, and as @i4mpi said it is useful information, as I was not able to find anything on google, and I am sure that other people will find the formula I have useful.

Comment: lol and there seems to be a down-voting spree both in here and the original question. I wonder if the number of negative votes is proportional to the number of comments I post in here

Comment: @MartinTaleski A couple points. Downvotes here on meta indicate people disagree with what you're saying and don't really equate to downvotes on StackOverflow (you don't lose points here and downvotes on SO are for poor questions). Second, you reference a question that asks a question of a similar broad scope and ask why that question isn't too broad. The question you linked is quite nearly 7 years old now. The rules of StackOverflow have changed quite a bit since then so while that question was within the rules then, it is no longer the case for new questions.

Comment: @MartinTaleski Additionally, you need to toughen up and stop taking downvotes so personally. Stubbornly insisting your question is on topic while multiple people explain to you in numerous different ways that it is not isn't terribly constructive. Are you here to just complain/bash the community or offer feedback and participate in open dialogue regarding your concerns? Seems the former to me.

Comment: @tnw actually I am following the critiques, and I have changed the question much since the original post, and I do believe that at this stage is a well thought question. It is even more important that you can not find another solution on the net for the problem, and I am not able to post my solution as an answer because the question is closed.

Comment: @MartinTaleski Just because you can't find the solution doesn't mean a question requesting it is on-topic.

Comment: Ok, can anyone tell me how to rewrite the question to be on topic? So far I made the question look better and I have read the manual (http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). The question does not fit into the off-topic, nor to the too broad section. The 7 down votes I received since I posted this meta thread look more like bandwagon voting, than anything that is meaningful. I am seriously trying to contribute and learn here.

Comment: come on guys, I need one more reopen vote I know you can do it... I even started getting upvotes on the question

Answer (score 5):

Your question has a few problems, which were also mentioned in comments:

- There is no example data. Dates could be formatted in many different ways, an that's why we need some examples, *in the question itself*. Clicking through to the PDF, I see a bunch of calendars and dates, which are highlighted in different ways. I'm still not sure what your input data actually looks like, and I can presume that you're not trying to parse the PDF.
- We need some samples of the input and output data you want.
- I'm not sure what a *broadcast year and month* actually *is*. It would be nice to tell us, again *in the question itself*. If it's too long a wikipedia link is okay though.
- *What have you tried ?* It is usually a good idea to show what you have tried (have you ?). This was asked in the cmments also. *"Gimme teh codez"* style questions are not generally appreciated, and the first version of your question was definitely such a question.
- I'm pretty sure this might have been asked before, especially since it's a common problem.

Your question was closed as too broad right after it was posted, and the first revision really *is* quite broad, hence the "on hold". Now that is has been improved, it should be possible to reopen it.

If you have a problem you should try to solve it first, and *then* ask on SO, not the other way around.

Comment: The first two points are actually not at all relevant. We don't need any example input as the question does not depend on date format (OP asks for a MySql or Python algorithm, one can assume that it should simply work with the respecitve date types of the languages). Example output is also uninteresting (a month and a year -> 2 numbers, nothing unclear about that), what's important is the definition of the broadcast calendar. Verified correct examples can serve as a test for an implementation, but it's not important for creating an algorithm at all.

Comment: The date format is not relevant to the question, as the date can be in any format. I did not want to add a 3 paragraph explanation in the question of what a broadcast calendar is. The question was actually directed to people that might have faced this problem, and might have such a formula, not at people that don't know what it is. I did a google search for it, nothing came up so I asked the question.

Comment: Ok, I have addressed all of the points in your answer, and I still get downvotes...

Answer (score -2):

After digging up on meta, I found this thread, which basically explains the bandwagon close votes and down votes, which I believe happened here:

[How can we discourage bandwagoning of Close Votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270690/how-can-we-discourage-bandwagoning-of-close-votes)

There was one suggestion to resubmit the improved question from scratch, which I plan to do, and see what comes up.

Comment: I hope, for your sake, it really is improved. Just asking us for an algorithm to do X is lazy at best, and usually doesn't get a good reception.

Comment: I don't think the linked question is really relevant. Your question was closed before you edited it, by a moderator. There is no close vote bandwagon since there was only one close vote. And lack of effort *is definitely* a good reason to downvote (see the downvote tooltip).