# Can you explain why my question was downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, downvotes, downvote-reason

I do not really understand why was my question downvoted. Can someone explain it to me, please?

[(Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953272/insert-an-object-between-two-objects-at-specific-indexes-in-an-array-in-java)

Comment: Probably because your question was a requirement spec rather than an actual programming issue?  Note - I did not downvote your question - not seen it till now.

Comment: You gave a nice title and formatted the question beautifully. But it lacks any research effort and some code that testifies that you understand something about programming and about your problem.

Comment: Two of your questions are *good* (one is a FAQ but at least you stated the problem well); the third may be a case for customer support, as it *does* concern "a programming tool" but seems not easily replicated. This one is either to broad, or asks for teh codez.

Comment: @Peter what was [that edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/271816/revisions) good for, are you on a badge hunt or something? Please stop bumping old questions with such pretty useless edits. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/296020/revisions

Answer (score 33):

There are two basic problems with your question.  The first one is the premise, which amounts to "How do I hammer a nail with a bottle?"  To which the obvious and trite answer is: "Don't use a bottle".  Not obvious to you perhaps, obvious however to many of the SO-users that see your question.  They'll choose the "This question is not useful" reason, largely because it is not useful to use bottles.

The second problem is that you show no evidence of having tried to find other programmers that used a bottle before.  The obvious Google query is "java insert element into an array".  The top three hits are SO questions.  Not obvious to you perhaps to use these keywords in a Google query, but just copy/pasting your question title into the Google query box show them as well.  Many SO-users will recognize this and they'll choose the "This question does not show any research effort" reason.

You hit two of the three reasons for a downvote.  The third (This question is not clear) did not apply.

Comment: I did search on Google. I might have not typed the good words on it, though (I'm a French teenager, vocabulary is not really my friend)

Comment: @utybo: pasting in your *exact title* gave [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384908/add-object-to-arraylist-at-specified-index) as a first hit (well, apart from your own Q then). Does that post answer your question?

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this with an *array*, not an `ArrayList`

Comment: @utybo: re, `"I did search on Google."` -- if you have done research or tried to solve your problem with code, prior to posting here, then please show the fruits of your labors in your question. The question appears as if you did no prior research or attempt whatsoever. Please consider this going forward.

Answer (score 5):

It was downvoted due to a lack of research. That's one of the stated reasons on the downvoted arrow.

I'm [not so sure why it was closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270586/when-why-a-question-with-accepted-answer-and-more-answers-is-deleted/270645#270645), it's certainly not too broad.

Comment: Too broad has become a fallback reason in the absence of "doesn't demonstrate a minimal understanding".

Comment: Using a shoe to hammer a nail works, right?

Comment: Can't find it atm but I believe Shog said somewhere "too broad" is applicaple for cases where the OP just dumps a task description, as doing the complete task for them would be too broad (even if the task is completely trivial). Furhtermore, _explaining_ a solution to an OP who shows absolutely no understanding of the topic would also be too broad; where would you even start? If OP fails to demonstrate his level of understanding, the question is unclear. And in general, the consensus is that bad questions should be closed regardless of reason, so I'm not sure why you reopened it...

Comment: @l4mpi If you can find his text and tell me how it applies to this question without [applying equally to these questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270586/when-why-a-question-with-accepted-answer-and-more-answers-is-deleted/270645#270645), I'll accept your argument. It's 'too broad' when the answer would have to fill a book (or even a chapter in a book) to be useful. otherwise it's not too broad.

Comment: @l4mpi, I think you're thinking of Robert Harvey, not Shog9, and if so you may want this answer of his: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226543/ There are others where he gives his interpretation of Too Broad: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a102937%20too%20broad%20

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, that was what I meant. There are similar meta.SO posts from him as well. George, 2 of the 3 the questions can be reasonably assumed to be _common_ problems that many developers face - validating mail addresses and IFs in SQL. Thus they can act as a useful reference. The C# one is bad IMO and should have been generalized to "find the difference in years between two datetime objects" (or cv'd as dup if that question already exists). But nobody needs a reference for a question like OPs as it's just a convoluted XY problem (use a real datastructure) which is not useful to others.

Comment: @l4mpi You still haven't mentioned what part of the question is too broad. If you read Robert's answer carefully, you'll notice he says something is too broad because of how much information you'd need to give to answer the question. In this case, you don't need that much at all; certainly not as much as would be required to be 'too broad'.