# How should we handle rude / unconstructive custom close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Two recent questions contain rude / unconstructive custom close reasons by high-rep users:

- [How can I typecast a function pointer that originally recieves void*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002814/how-can-i-typecast-a-function-pointer-that-originally-recieves-void) *(deleted by author)*
- [How to check if string contains particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941426/how-to-check-if-string-contains-particular-character#comment42426757_26941426)

The first one was something along the lines of:

> "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading a basic tutorial."

And the second one is:

> "Other: Try something at least? Perhaps read the book"

Thankfully these questions haven't been closed, but the first one accumulated 3 votes and the second one 2 votes. You can always flag comments, but how do you handle rude or unconstructive custom close reasons?

Comment: The first one has been deleted. I have flagged some of the rude responses as "not constructive"

Comment: @GrantWinney: A quick Google could have saved the asker from asking, too.  Finding duplicates is more annoying than it needs to be, which is why nobody does it.  Also, you're welcome to find the dupe yourself.  I'm sure it exists.

Comment: @remyabel, And the sad truth is that [people here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5763/why-sf-is-failing-the-dismal-future-of-serverfault) actually upvote the rude unconstructive comments you listed.

Answer (score 11):

The close reason was a bit not-constructive.

And, of course, lack of research has never been a close reason.

In this case, lack of research is a reason to downvote the question.

[Previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88521/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220629/question-where-no-research-has-been-conducted-at-all), [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/proposal-for-new-close-reason-no-prior-research-work), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257979/16587), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271816/can-you-explain-why-my-question-was-downvoted), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275689/is-this-constructive-or-am-i-just-being-rude), [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270690/how-can-we-discourage-bandwagoning-of-close-votes).

Comment: I'm sure you can find a few more _previously's_.

Comment: @Bluefeet [Just wait until I get going](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-olpiEGUTMHU/VDlkrX35T2I/AAAAAAAAKOY/ttcL466NFxs/s1600/princess%2Bbride%2Bgif.png).

Comment: Note: If anyone can find a Gif of that picture; I'd be forever in your debt.

Comment: [Inconceivable](http://jennadoesbooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/animated-princess-bride-inconceivable.gif)!!

Comment: Just for confirmation, the whole "for professional and enthusiastic programmers"-bit should be roundly ignored (aside from down-voting, which means we still accumulate those posts)?

Comment: @Deduplicator Who said anything about ignoring it? [Questions like this have been here from the beginning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270645/16587).

Comment: @Deduplicator Incidentally, it's 'enthusiast programmers', not 'enthusiastic programmers'.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with whether or not the question should be closed, just that the close reasons are rude. Sometimes people opt to leave rude comments or close vote instead of downvoting - nothing wrong with that. But it seems unnecessary to be snarky.

Comment: What would be immensely helpful is if the asker could see the close reasons before their post is closed so they could make adjustments when no comment is left by those requesting the close. It might also cut down on the number of rude comments left about the closing.