# Can we agree to not vote (mostly) on linked questions/answers in meta?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta

It's not uncommon to see [questions like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271816/can-you-explain-why-my-question-was-downvoted?rq=1) in meta. Now I don't want to discuss the meta voting culture (why that question got -5 and 10 downvotes is beyond me). The OP came and asked a question about his question which led to a flurry of downvotes on his question putting it at -29.

This is just one example - **I'm sure you've all seen questions and answers gain a considerable amount of upvotes or a considerable amount of downvotes after being posted in meta**. Now - when we see "injustice" our instinct is to try and correct it which is good. It also really clouds meta discussion itself, discourages people from asking questions on how to improve here and causes more problems than it solves in my opinion.

Assuming we can't get a technical solution for this - do you think we can agree as a community not to vote on questions and answers posted on meta if that's how we got to them? (disregarding special cases)

I'm interested in what the community thinks about this issue, and what people think should be done alternatively (or whether you think it's an issue at all).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  I forgot to downvote the original question, I've now fixed that.

Comment: It would be awesome if downvoters left a comment as this is a discussion. I'm genuinely interested in why.

Comment: Honestly if the "referer" from [so] is from Meta then all voting buttons should be disabled. With some fooling around you may be able to bypass it but I believe most people won't put in that effort.

Comment: It is a pretty nonsensical proposition.  Do you *really* expect SO users to not vote when a post gets featured at Hacker News or Reddit or in an SE newletter?  How are we supposed to find the good content?  Or are you just wishing the cr*p away without having to do something about it and never having to be reminded about it?  Well, don't we all.

Comment: You're asking if we could "good-will" away the "meta" effect. I don't see that happening on a good will basis, if only because the community is so diverse and fluid. Getting it to agree on anything like this would be like the over-used cliche of "herding cats". Note also that sometimes the meta effect results in magnification of up-votes, so it is not always bad for the poster.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268171/stop-mob-downvoting-users-on-the-main-site-for-their-actions-there-and-their-opi

Comment: The meta effect works in two ways, not only downvoting... But: it can effectively be summed up with "Hey everybody! *Look at this question!*, and thus simply draws more eyes -- and votes -- than when appearing (shortly) on the main page.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that we can, no.

There is already a "problem" with Stack Overflow voting in that the magnitude of a post's score (in either direction) is largely a function of the number of views it received. [1]

Whether this is actually a problem *per se* has been questioned before [2], but certainly I don't believe that attempting to introduce an artificial and voluntary exception to this phenomenon is going to be either effective or fair. All I can see it achieving is spoiling the correlation between "number of views" and a post's magnitude, preventing us from ever feasibly reasoning about said correlation as it applies to individual posts in the future.

In short, that a post becomes well-popularised by a Meta post is no different than a post becoming well-popularised by a famous spamming it across Twitter or Reddit. To say that a really good post or a really bad post should not end up with +520 or -21 score just because lots more people than usual had the opportunity to read and vote on the post seems counter-productive to me.

That being said, in an ideal world, I'd still like to see a solution to the situation more generally. Ultimately, though, we should probably try not to get too worked up about a post having -21 rather than -1 — the thing to take away is that the majority of voters thought the post was not useful, regardless of how many voters there actually were.

[1] [Mitigating publicity-driven vote inflation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96226/155739)
[2] [What to do about rep inflation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/155739)

Comment: Well - the difference between becoming popularized by Meta and by Twitter or Reddit is that often the author themselves post on meta and they're asking about using the site.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: More often, IMO, it's someone else berating some post for some perceived infraction of the site's rules.