# Is asking 'why is this question being downvoted' acceptable here?

Tags: discussion

Searching this site seems to show conflicting answers. Take, for instance, [Can you explain why my question was downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271816/can-you-explain-why-my-question-was-downvoted) - the top answer is highly upvoted. But the question (the Meta question) is downvoted. So - is it acceptable or not?

Comment: Note that meta voting is different from other StackOverflow sites. A down-vote here does not mean that someone thinks you've posted a poor meta question, but rather just that they disagree with your question's premise. Also a down-vote here has no effect on your reputation or ability to ask questions.

Comment: A *lot* of questions get down-voted on the main site, if everyone came here to ask why, we'd be flooded.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know the difference. But in this case, it a) doesn't make much sense. b) There are conflicting vote patterns on these questions. About `a down-vote here has no effect on your ... ability to ask questions` - is inexact. It _can_ ban you from asking questions here on meta.

Comment: @TZHX So you're saying it's not accepted? If so - you can post that as an answer. And while you're at it, perhaps you have an explanation as to why some of these questions are upvoted...

Comment: I don't think that that's true. I don't think that down-votes on *meta* can ban you from asking questions on meta or on the SO site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ban on meta only. (I now clarified my comment above.) Try it, ask many bad questions and see... :)

Comment: @ispiro it's not not *accepted*, it's just discouraged and for the majority of cases, bringing a down-voted question to the attention of the core meta crowd (who are typically more interested in quality than other users) and asking them to *look* for reasons to down-vote it, is going to lead to more down-votes.

Comment: @TZHX actually, it normally leads to more "votes" in general.

Comment: I suspect that upvotes are rarely a result of the meta effect.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but a down-voted question has already had some people decide it's worthy of a down-vote. If you come and ask why it was down voted from people who more than likely weren't the voters, you're asking them to imagine anything they could find in your question worthy of a down-vote. If a question is good quality and had a couple of down-votes, it may get some up, but in the **majority** of cases (as I said), it's going to be down votes.

Comment: *Ban on meta only.* I thought that was just on the Meta.StackExchange site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's OK to ask *after* you've done your research.  Have you sat down and read your question like someone who knows nothing about your question?  Is it useful, clear, researched?  Or is it closer to not showing research effort, unclear or not useful?  If you've done your best (and can explain what you've done and found) it is ok.  We want to help people learn how to ask better questions, but like the main site, *we expect you to try to solve it for yourself first* and not outsource your thinking at the first sign of trouble.

Also, asking about it for a single downvote is just annoying.  One vote doesn't necessarily mean your question is bad.  A couple means it's time to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

> So - is it acceptable or not?

It was marked as a (valid) duplicate.

Duplicates are acceptable in general, since they can build up a network of useful questions and answers that can be reached from many entry points.

Though an obvious duplicate lacking enough research from the OP's side is prone for downvotes because the question was more or less *trivial*.

Answers for such duplicates are still answers and live in the answer universe.

---

The pattern of downvoted questions and highly upvoted answers is pretty usual on Meta Stack Overflow (and other site specific Meta sites). May be [Shog9's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617) sheds a bit of light on it.

Comment: Thanks. Though this doesn't make too much sense in this case, since if it's a duplicate - it means it shouldn't be answered. And I'm surprised that the respectable answerer there chose to answer it. Downvoted questions with upvoted answers make more sense in cases of feature requests.

Comment: @ispiro _it means it shouldn't be answered_ There are often answers for duplicates, that doesn't mean these are invalid actually. I didn't look at your particular sample so far. Maybe for that particular case you're right.

Comment: @ispiro the "no research effort" is still a criteria for down votes on meta -- the highly up-voted answer to that question is basically an expanded version of the down-vote tool-tip, slightly tailored to the specific case.