# Why do we punish harsh comments and not lazy questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, close-reasons

It seems that we are gradually removing the ability of long standing users to actively maintain the culture and communication of Stack Overflow in favour of new users who do not respect the culture of high quality questions and answers. It's starting to get to me.

- I didn't like the removal of the close reason "no research effort" - when a user shows no effort, that is a perfectly valid reason.
- I didn't like the ability to state "What have you tried?" which in a case like below is again valid, because they have shown *zero effort* in their question.
- And I downright hated the removal of the "-1" prefix to comments (as did many others).

[image: Example Q: how-retrieve-id-from-link]

So the question remains, why is the Stack Overflow staff so hellbent on punishing long standing users who effectively act as free staff who moderate the site, when new low effort questions keep flooding in?

Search is getting good enough and space is getting cheap enough that good moderation isn't as necessary as it once was.

What is my incentive to help Stack Overflow, when they seem to remove everything I liked about it?

> **Stack Overflow** is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by *you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Except now low quality questions from people who show no enthusiasm are welcomed. I'm not even concerned about professionalism, I'd just like a little enthusiasm. When you put in zero code into your question, that's *not enthusiastic*.

And its not run by *us*, as changes (like the dreaded and much protested removal of `+1` comments) are unilaterally put in place.

So in summary, why does Stack Overflow keep forcing kid gloves on long-standing users at the protection of new users who show zero interest in the site?

Specifically, why do we support help vampires by allowing them to come along, ask their question, get an answer from some repfarmer, and then shuffle along their way.

Why can't we retain the harsh gatekeepers of old that actually encouraged high quality work?

edit: True to form, in the time it took to write this rant the question I captured has been answered: [How retrieve ID from link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976693/how-retrieve-id-from-link)

Comment: This has got to be a duplicate question....

Comment: I'm curious to know why this is getting downvotes.

Comment: Because someone disagrees with your premise, that's all. Votes on meta has significantly different implications from votes on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I understand the difference. What I meant was "why do people disagree enough to downvote"?

Comment: [Here's one relevant question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments)

Comment: `"why do people disagree enough to downvote"` -- ??? who the heck knows? Wait and they might comment.

Comment: You'll see I have commented many times in that thread. And you'll notice it has **over 200** downvotes, meaning a lot of people *did not like the change*. Except it was introduced without consulting the community first.

Comment: The question you linked is too broad. Even though they got rid of "Minimal understanding/effort" there are still 11 close reasons. The removal of that reason really hasn't effected ability to close questions much at all. Sure, some bad questions have been kept alive because of it, but chances are most of them fit another of the 11 close reasons. The -1 and WHYT in comments is rather trivial and really easy to work around if you so please.

Comment: ***Its not about losing one particular close reason, this is showing a pattern of change.*** Sure, we can manually write "no research effort" as a custom close reason. And we can write "-2 bad question" or "What code have you written", but should we have too? If we use this site, shouldn't we have a say in how we use it, rather than one mod unilaterally going "I don't like when people call code bad, so 'bad code' is no longer allowed in comments".

Comment: What is your proposal? If you are concerned about bad questions remaining open, there are still close reasons that easily fill the "No Research." "Too broad", "Unclear" or "Off Topic->Include Code" can cover pretty much every instance of "No Research".

Comment: Firstly, I'd like the mods to not make unilateral changes. Especially to comment rules. If possible I'd like to have my +1 and -1 comments back. Sometimes I like to explain what I voted and why.

Comment: Also the tool tip for downvoting clearly says that downvoting is for not showing any research effort.

Comment: You seem to be under the misconception that SE is a democracy. It isn't. It's a commercial enterprise, and the owners and employees of that enterprise can make any change they want without anyone's permission. While they are receptive to user input in many cases, they're free to make any changes they'd like without consulting users, including stopping people from introducing comment clutter and noise. If that's a problem for someone, that someone always has the option to take their business elsewhere.

Comment: For someone intimately involved in use of the product, @KenWhite, "because it's a business and they can do what they want" isn't a great argument. Asking Coca-Cola, as a consumer, why they changed their soda formula to taste like earwax would be equally legitimate. Neither company _owes_ its users an answer, let alone a change of course, but _asking_ is not unreasonable. Especially when the company has a dedicated user feedback medium such as this.

Comment: [- Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not? - No...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/839601)

Comment: SE simply likes to minimize the number of complaints that stream into their email inbox.  The kind of complaints that users file when they don't get what they want.  Obviously the "guaranteed money back" clause that's prevalent in the USA to ensure customer satisfaction doesn't work so well on a free web site.  So they complain about anything else they can come up with.  Nothing that SE staff can do about it, they are not actively involved in the Q+A at all, other than removing the triggers.  The occasional meta rant isn't nearly enough to tip the balance.

Comment: @HansPassant [citation needed]

Comment: @Will [not quite so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773): comment like your can be wiped out with a single flag, due to having "trigger word"

Answer (score 20):

> Why do we punish harsh comments and not lazy questions?

This whole question is just... laughable.

Downvotes have an in-built meaning associated with them:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

You're adding useless noise to the site by *duplicating* that comment. Don't do that. Such comments should be flagged as the noise they are, and deleted. Stop *adding* to the problem. Nobody is **"punishing" you** because you weren't allowed to leave a *bad* comment, that's asinine. How could you possibly spin that to be a "punishment" against you?

> So the question remains, why is the StackOverflow staff so hellbent on punishing long standing users who effectively act as free staff who moderate the site, when new low effort questions keep flooding in?

That is a **laughable** interpretation of what is going on here.

Don't post bad comments, that's it. Nobody downvoted you, you didn't lose any rep, you were prevented from taking an action that would have negatively impacted the signal:noise ratio of the site.

> So in summary, why does StackOverflow keep forcing kid gloves on long-standing users

Seriously, because you couldn't down-vote **and** leave a `-1 i downvoted this` comment?

Comment: And what about `+1` comments that people argued for in the question? Where its `+1 but you really should address X` its concise and contributes to less cruft.

Comment: --1 Also, you did not address the fact that I'm not complaining about any one of the changes implemented, but **the pattern of changes to comments without consultation**.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Mods don't make "unilateral changes" without consultation. Mods *cannot* make such changes. Stack Overflow *employees* make those changes, and they have every right to. They are a *for profit* company, and this is their *product*. Your sense of entitlement here is astounding. "Some mod" didn't make these decisions, the community's consensus has *repeatedly* been that the comments you're trying to leave are noisy garbage.

Comment: @meagar A resounding [-143 score on the question that introduced the ban on -1 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) isn't community consensus that they are garbage, and is quite the opposite.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You mean that question where they tested and collected data over two months and proved that it's a *good feature*? Yes, as I said: It's a product, run by a company, who get the final say. Guess what: It **works**. It prevented you from leaving a **bad comment**, exactly as it was intended.

Comment: No, they showed that less of those comments got through. That doesn't prove it improved the site. Those stats don't show if poor questions have crept up, or return new users are not adapting to the rules, or if people are leaving few comments and answers because they are tired of the blocks in place.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You can interpret that data however you like. I don't care, it's not relevant. Your question and my answer are about your ridiculous spinning of the situation, that you personally and users in general are somehow being "punished". Regardless of whether people like or hate the automatic blocking of `-1` comments, such comments **as yours** have repeatedly been decided as **noise**, to be flagged as such, and removed. Nobody is punishing you, despite your attempt to post bad content to the site, so get over it. There isn't even an answerable *question* in there, just a rant.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr "I'm complaining about ... the pattern of changes" No you're not. The title of this question isn't "why do mods unilaterally change policies". Maybe in your head it sounds like that's what you're asking, but that's not the question that ended up here.

Comment: @meagar Perhaps a bit Off-Topic, but your (first) comment is overly simplistic. SE's main money-making asset is the content provided *by us, the community*. It's *us* that make the money around here, not the people who work at SE, they merely *facilitate us* in our ability to make money for them... So yes, it does seem that users have at least *some* sense of "entitlement" (how much exactly is a another question), and in general SE seems to recognize this (which is why we have meta).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No, my comment is exactly accurate. We have exactly as much democracy as the owners of the product give us, no more, no less. They **are** a for-profit company, and they **are** free to do whatever they want with **their product**. That is not an over simplification, that is completely accurate.

Comment: @meagar That wasn't really my point. My point isn't about legality of who 'owns' what, it's about whether a constructively contributing user (and thus money-making user) may have a "sense of entitlement" (small or large) to complain about the site's policy.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Everybody is entitled to complain about whatever they want. If you try to claim that automatically preventing bad comments is some how punitive, that should be called out. Just because some of your contributions are constructive doesn't mean we should allow you to do whatever you want.

Comment: isn't this answer a bit... harsh?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No

Answer (score 10):

This question is crazy.

We punish lazy questions with downvotes and closure (and even deletion). You know, things that *actually lead towards a question-ban*. In fact, we do it so well that *those* users complain about it here on Meta (ironically enough).

We hardly punish harsh comments *at all*. Be egregious enough and you can get put in the penalty box, thats about it. Otherwise the worst thing that can happen is you can't post the comment or it gets deleted. Thats not "punishment" in any sense of the word.

Also remember that, due to community feedback, you *can* leave "-1" or "+1" in your comment, you just have to include a detailed explanation (not just "What have you tried" which doesn't really help anyone).

And beyond the signal:noise ratio, which this is trying to improve, we also do need to realize that there are actual people on the other end. While I am in no way suggesting compromising the quality of the site, treating other users with respect while cleaning up their garbage is still very important. Some of the restrictions (like the one on LMGTFY) are due in large part to that (plus those comments just not being constructive at all).

Answer (score 7):

You can 'punish' a bad question.

The best way to do so is by downvoting it.

Downvoting ensures

- a question asker is rate-limited and then banned if they get too many downvotes (similarly with an answerer)
- The community can delete a post if it goes under a zero score; making it easier to clean up bad posts
- The OP has a concrete negative reinforcement for their behavior. People can ignore comments (or flag ones they don't like -- I see that all the time), but they can't ignore downvotes.

On the other hand, a comment like:

> -1 this question shows no effort

Doesn't tell the OP how to fix the issue. "Show effort"?  [Some of the best questions don't show any effort.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270645/16587)

If you're leaving a comment for the OP, make it actionable. How could they show more effort? What could they do to get a +1 from you?  Telling them you downvoted and they should show effort makes the comment about the downvote, and not about the reason you downvoted.  Better to just downvote, and if you're going to leave a comment, make it actionable.

Similarly, "What have you tried"? doesn't help anyone.  At best they'll respond to you in the comments (instead of the question), and sometimes, they shouldn't try anything (see the answer I linked to).

A better thing to do would be to tell the OP what's missing:

> "From what you've written, I don't have x, y, and z, that I need to be able to solve your issue; if you edit your question with (a, b, and c) it'll help us answer you."

If you're going to leave a comment; make it actionable.  Those comments aren't allowed because they're not actionable.

Answer (score 5):

> now low quality questions from people who show no enthusiam are welcomed.

We welcome them with a full embrace of throttling, banning, and downvotes.

Can you imagine if this happened to "harsh"<sup><sub>*1*</sub></sup> comments? If we truly punished them the poster would receive a comment throttle, negative reputation, and perhaps even a comment ban. But we don't, we just slap you with a small red styled element that essentially asks you to rephrase. What a *harsh* punishment that is.

Also, your "true to form" "rep farmers" (ridiculous term) have a combined total reputation of 90. Not 90,000, not 9,000, 90.

<sub>1. Harsh: Cruel or severe. I personally do not think `-1` or `What have you tried?` are harsh. However, they have been deemed to be counterproductive and that is where the prevention comes from. In my opinion, harsh comments would be more along the lines of direct insults or ad hominem attacks.</sub>