# Is this question suitable for SO or should it be closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I have been on SO for a while now and feel this question is not suitable for SO as it is either asking for a tool or asking for some code to be written without showing any basic understanding of the languages tagged or any relevant code of any kind.

[**Question here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028268/how-to-create-links-or-divs-for-a-part-of-image?noredirect=1#comment46298159_29028268)

I put a quick answer in the comments and also stated this is not suitable for SO and how they could fix that (including relevant code etc). Another user has told me I am wrong and the question is suitable for SO.

I would like to know if I am indeed wrong and this question is suitable for SO?

If this is so then I have been looking at these question wrong since I started here and it would be nice to correctly comment/answer these types of questions.

Comment: The question is not too broad. It should not be closed.  I've [talked about this before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270645/16587).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what's wrong with the question. It gives context of the problem and asks whether it's possible to solve the problem with JS, HTML or CSS. It's hard to give relevant code (as you put it) when you're asking if something is possible.

The answer is: yes, it is possible, by using the HTML `<map>` element. At no point did OP ask "here is my image, give me code to make the eyes and ears and nose clickable".

Perhaps the question could be edited for spelling and grammar, but otherwise it's OK.

Answer (score -3):

You're correct. The question is trivial (if taken overliterally) or too broad (if the request to know whether it's possible is taken with its usual rhetorical of "how can I do it then"). The former, while technically on-topic, is useless garbage; the latter is of course one of the close reasons.