# Why was my off-topic flag on a question about parsing mathematical expressions declined?

Tags: discussion, scope, declined-flags

I had flagged this question: [What are the cases to be considered while parsing a mathematical expression(brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29396477/what-are-the-cases-to-be-considered-while-parsing-a-mathematical-expressionbrac) for closure because it belongs on a different site (I originally wanted to flag for migration  <strike>to Mathematics, but I couldn't find it (and it didn't seem quite right))</strike> so I flagged as off topic (didn't find the correct site to migrate to in the list at the time).

It has since been declined. However, this brings up 2 points:

1. Why? Is this really not off topic? After some searching, I understand that this is likely because 3 people in the review queue saw fit to leave it open. To people who glanced over the question quickly, I would agree that it may seem like a legitimate question - however, if you really look at the question and what it's asking, it doesn't belong on SO.

   Just to make sure I wasn't wrong in flagging it, I had done research as to exactly what constitutes as "on topic" in SO ([Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)) And according to said metapost, the question does **not** belong on SO.
2. Now that my flag has been declined, there's no way for me to reflag it for migration (assuming the flag for moderator attention shouldn't be used for this purpose)! Assuming I flagged it incorrectly before as off-topic, now that I know there's a migration flag, why can't I flag it to migrate to say, the CS.SE site?

Comment: How, *exactly* did you flag the post?

Comment: Using the flag button, navigating to the "blatantly off topic", because I (initially) couldn't find the proper migration site. Even if the question isn't "blatantly" off topic, I still think it's off topic though.

Comment: @Servy Blatantly off-topic is available to < 3k users who flag for closure. It is not available to >3k close voters, they need to write a custom close reason in the text box.

Comment: For the record, there is *no way* that belongs at mathematics. Although I don't understand the question (hence VTC for unclear what you are asking), he certainly is asking about parsing math expressions, not using them. No way that is on-topic at Math.SE

Comment: Also, it appears the OP wanted to code for this in Java, not just a determination if they needed other rules. I don't think it's OT for Stack Overflow, but it is a bit broad.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker wouldn't that (just asking for code) in itself be off topic, or am I wrong here? I was under the impression that you ask a question on SO under 2 main circumstances: 1) Code doesn't work, or 2) IDE is broken - Of which neither are related to the question, especially since OP didn't provide code or show effort of trying to code it first.

Comment: @Aify Asking for code is not off topic.  In fact, some of our best questions and answers come from people asking for code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270645/16587

Comment: Too bad it wasn't closed as a dup of [Parenthesis/Brackets Matching using Stack algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874176/parenthesis-brackets-matching-using-stack-algorithm) (even has code!). Maybe a helpful mod will merge the question into the other and delete the post to get rid of the comments and down votes on the user that the meta effect is attracting.

Comment: Those questions aren't really similar enough to merge at this point, @MichaelT; it'd take some heavy editing to let the answers match, I suspect.

Comment: @Shog9 the answer for the new one is exactly a good fit to answer the other (and better than some there). Asking for code part which was edited back in is also answered in the other. The proper handling of mismatched brackets is also answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As Bradley noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289223/why-was-my-off-topic-flag-on-a-question-about-parsing-mathematical-expressions-d#comment171799_289223), this question is not off-topic. It *might* be answerable on another site (although probably not Math), but that alone does not make a question off-topic either - there are *lots* of sites where certain programming questions are appropriate (when they overlap heavily with the main topic), but if we're still talking about programming questions then they're still on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Lemme repeat that for emphasis: **don't flag stuff as off-topic *just* because it could've been asked somewhere else.** [Be a bit jealous of your site...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)