# Question on-hold as "off topic", asking for research

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

I recently asked a question that was questionably broad. I had narrowed down what I needed to a very specific "how-to" question. Several people commented saying it was too broad so I narrowed it down even more. One person finally gave me an answer to the question, but in the form of a comment.

The frustrating part is that same person voted to put the question on hold just a few minutes after he had commented a solution. Now neither he nor anyone else can "answer" the question. But since it is considered "off-topic", it tells me I should do more research and narrow down my question. But now that someone has presented me with an answer what's the point of clarifying the question? Why would someone answer the question and then lock it down to make me clarify it?

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007481/rendering-an-image-in-an-image-with-gd

Comment: Because the question as it stands still isn't a good fit for the site unless it receives more clarifications (i'm assuming that is still the case, i haven't visited your question yet.) The fact that an answer is found doesn't make a broad question not so broad.

Comment: It is a "can you Google this for me" question.  Somebody googled it for you, posting links as an answer tends to be frowned upon and very unpleasant to have to maintain, so he used a comment instead.  You got what you came for, little reason to be disappointed.

Comment: Granted. But why would someone answer a question and then put it on hold? It doesn't make sense! What do they expect me to do?

Comment: He didn't answer it, he commented. If he had answered your question with that article as the sole body of the answer, he would have been downvoted cause it's a bad answer for the site--your question invites bad answers because it's also a bad question for the site. Which is why he voted to close it. You're not "expected" to do anything, unless you want to improve the question and get more answers, but it seems you're done now.

Comment: @eddie_cat Got to it before I did.

Comment: @RamsaySmith We're after programming problems and programming solutions. Without any code, it is hard to call your question a programming problem. It is, instead, a research problem. The only valid help to your research problem is to research for you, which some one did because they are nice. Their willingness to help with that doesn't change your question into being a programming problem, so the question is properly closed. Everything about our process worked like it should, and you encountered a nice & helpful person to boot. All is as it should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answering a question which you vote to close as off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270418/answering-a-question-which-you-vote-to-close-as-off-topic)

Comment: I thought it was a great comment/answer - the poster found what you were looking for in less than an hour.   Maybe your own research techniques need an update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But now that someone has presented me with an answer what's the point of clarifying the question? Why would someone answer the question and then lock it down to make me clarify it?

If you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007481/rendering-an-image-in-an-image-with-gd), there are a few reasons for closing and then commenting:

Your question had a few reasons to be closed:

1. You wanted an answer to a question where the answer would have taken an article's length to answer.
2. There wasn't actually any code; so the best anyone could do would be to point you in the right direction
3. We have a close reason specifically for people who want an 'off site resource'. As you indicated in your comment on the answer, that's what you needed.

[image]

The closer commented because they wanted to help you. They closed because your question, as written, was off topic for Stack Overflow.  Those two are not mutually exclusive. It wouldn't even be unheard of for that person to answer your question and then vote to close it (although some frown on this approach).

One of the reasons for putting a question on hold (or closing it, if you're an oldy) is to give you a chance to fix what's wrong with it.  You have an opportunity to turn this question into a useful resource for future visitors. Take what you've learned from the article, and use it to scope your question more narrowly.

Comment: Still, that person could have actually answered the question and then closed it.

Comment: @RamsaySmith Some people frown upon that approach. given that if you don't improve your question it will probably be deleted (And possibly count towards you being rate-limited), the onus is on you to fix it so it can be re-opened. Both for the community's sake and your own future here.

Comment: @RamsaySmith closing is usually signal that a question _should not be answered_. Answering questions that are deemed off-topic is bad because it does not teach people not to ask off-topic questions. Furthermore, the answer would either amount to posting the link (bad idea, links rot, the answer is useless without it) or to write up a self-contained answer to your rather broad question, which would be a considerable investment of effort from the poster.